# Unable to make a 301 domain redirection for a long url in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I just moved my siteA.com to siteB.com. I am trying to put traffic from siteA.com to siteB.com.

**My .htaccess file which 301 redirection does not work**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.siteA.com/home/3-Tips-in-Math.html$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http://www.siteB.com/home/3-Tips-in-Math.html" [R=301,L]
```

**How can you make the above code to work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.siteB\.example$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.siteB.example%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```